# Hiding output of a macro

Tags: macros, output

Is there a way to get a macro to hide its output but still do the logic with counters etc.?

I'm stuck on the definition of macro `\dontoutput` below.

```
% \documentclass, \usepackage, ...

\newcount\innercount

\def\dontoutput#1{#1} % ???

\long\def\inner#1{\advance\innercount 1\relax}

\long\def\outer#1{
  \innercount 0\relax
  \dontoutput{#1}    % call it, increment counters in \inner, but don't output anything!
  Inner called \the\innercount times.
  \def\inner##1{##1} % we want to output it too now.
  #1                 % call again
}

\begin{document}
  \outer{
    a
    \inner{b}
    \inner{c}
    \inner{d}
    e
  }
\end{document}

% Outputs:  a e Inner called 3 times. abcde
% I'd like:     Inner called 3 times. abcde
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\newcounter{inner}
\def\inner#1{#1}
\def\outer#1{%
  {\sbox0{\setcounter{inner}{0}\def\inner##1{\stepcounter{inner}}#1}}%
  Inner called \theinner\ times. #1}
```

Command on LaTeX counters act globally; so we typeset the argument of `\outer` in a box where we set the counter to zero and define `\inner` to step the counter. The default definition of `\inner`, which is reinstated outside the box, is to typeset its argument.

Following Martin's suggestion I have also put the box assignment in a group, for greater safety. The command `\sbox` builds a box saving it into a storage bin, but typesetting nothing in the document. However all commands are performed, in particular we can redefine `\inner` to have a different meaning, since when we enter a box construction another group is opened. The group around the `\sbox` operation ensures that the storage bin will be forgotten at the group's end.

Usually one writes

```
\newsavebox{\mybox}
```

in the preamble and then `\sbox{\mybox}{...}` in order to `\usebox{\mybox}` somewhere else; however, `\mybox` refers just to a certain internal number and the numbers 0, 2, 4, 6, and 8 are reserved for "scratch boxes" and one can freely use them for purposes such as the present one.

Comment: You might want to wrap the box assignment into a group as well to keep it local.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I had to lookup the \sbox command - do I understand it correctly - in that it sort of saves its content (whatever happens inside the braces) and doesn't print it?

Comment: @MartinJaniczek: It stores it in a box register which are usually declared using `\newbox\mybox`, but are actually just numbers. Here you store it in box #0, which is often used for temporary usages. To typeset the box (even multiple times) use `\usebox{\mybox}` or `\usebox{0}` (or even `\usebox\mybox` and `\usebox0 `).

Answer (score 2):

You can store the content into a box which is not used, as egreg already showed.

You could also use `\nullfont` to switch off any text output. However, paragraphs are still inserted AFAIK, so `\let\par\relax` would also be useful. Finally you want to disable that any command switches to a real font again, so `\let\selectfont\relax` should also be added. Either put these in a group or save and restore the original definitions (first `\let\origfoo\foo` then later `\let\foo\origfoo`). You should use `\normalfont` after restoring `\selectfont` in the latter case.

Usually the use of a box is preferable, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative way to switch off the output. The box way suits me better, but it's nice to know it can be done this way too.

Comment: I would not recommend this approach, as math would be typeset nonetheless. Using a box is quite safer; if paragraphs can be expected, it's sufficient to say `\setbox0=\vbox{...}`.