# To emulate lookahead for variable evaluation, run a macro laden block of text twice. How to suppress text output in the first pass?

Tags: macros, arithmetic

I'm writing a little supplement for my friends, we use the GURPS tabletop role playing game system.
This system uses a points pool to buy aspects of characters. I would like to have the point total of a character at the beginning of the stat block, but to calculate the point total, I have inserted counters into the stat block.

Since LaTeX does not really have look ahead for that kind of thing (hence the aux file and co), I'd like to just run the stat block twice, but suppress the output of the first pass.

I realize that this is 'cheapen it out' a bit and I should just create a local 'preamble' setup with only the data, but there are so many characters and I'm generating the statblock from an external tool and some processing inbetween.

Now, usually I would do the calculation of the total there, but there are some complications I don't want to go into detail here for brevity, I adjust some costs manually, etc.

Anyway. The core of the question is, is it possible to evaluate TeX without printing any text, and only do evaluations of variables and commands?

If so, what's the command for it?

I'm basically asking about something like \makeatletter and \makeatother.

A macro to wrap around the block like

```
\documentclass{article}
\mycounter
\begin{document}
\suppressPrinting %fictitious/unknown macro I am asking for here
My total is \themycounter 
Cool ability [50] \addtocounter{mycounter}{50}
Cool ability [50] \addtocounter{mycounter}{50}
Cool ability [50] \addtocounter{mycounter}{50}
\resumePrinting

My total is \themycounter % now holds 150
Cool ability [50] \addtocounter{mycounter}{50}
Cool ability [50] \addtocounter{mycounter}{50}
Cool ability [50] \addtocounter{mycounter}{50}
\setcounter{mycounter}{0}
\end{document}
```

I suppose my question is basically a duplicate of:
[Hiding output of a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38338/hiding-output-of-a-macro)

But that one is nine years old. Anything changed in that regard?

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587462/latex3-elegant-way-to-forward-reference-a-counter-with-a-future-value/588071#588071 for one possibility.  If you were able to edit your question and provide a small but complete code for what you are attempting (rather than just a code fragment), I might be able to adapt the referenced answer to it.  But with just a code fragment, it is hard to fully interpret your need.

Comment: why don't you want to use the aux-file and label/ref? That is much more robust and faster then parsing arbitrary text to find some commands.

Comment: My intent is to hide text output while still evaluating all the macros. If I edited my post then I'd only add the documentclass preamble, begin and end document, and that's that. I have nothing else to add to that.

That said, I think https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38338/hiding-output-of-a-macro 
Is the way to go for that, adding the contents to a 'box' and never using the box...

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I use the aux and label/ref...for references. This is about evaluating some macros but not printing anything while doing so. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: ! Undefined control sequence.
l.5 My total is \themycounter

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, I messed up providing the 'working example', since it's technically impossible to write one (if one does not know something that works, one cannot provide an example where it does) , so I carelessly jotted something down. 

As for the aux file, I don't know enough to use it properly. Which I suppose is a question in itself.

Comment: even after your edit what is `\mycounter` intended to do in the preamble?

Comment: Hurrrr took you longer to fix the example you didn't need than to write your answer, eh? 

I hope I never ever have to interact with you again. 
Provide me an example... provide a screenshot. Here's my screenshot:
Oh, there's nothing on it? Yeah that's cause I was asking to evaluate a block of TeX without printing it, like I said in my fekkin question. Evaluate it without printing using some TeX construct I DO NOT KNOW and therefore cannot show in the 'working example' 

Working example with something I don't know. And a screenshot of a screen I want empty. Damn autists.

Comment: I have provided you _two_ answers what more do you want:-) Obviously in a question site a minimal working example isn't supposed to be an example of the _solution_ it is supposed to be an example of the _problem_ and if it stops on line one with a syntax error then it is not that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fixing unrelated errors in your example, you can do the first pass in a box.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\begin{document}

\begin{lrbox}{0}
My total is \themycounter\ 
Cool ability [50] \addtocounter{mycounter}{50}
Cool ability [50] \addtocounter{mycounter}{50}
Cool ability [50] \addtocounter{mycounter}{50}
\end{lrbox}

My total is \themycounter\ % now holds 150
Cool ability [50] \addtocounter{mycounter}{50}
Cool ability [50] \addtocounter{mycounter}{50}
Cool ability [50] \addtocounter{mycounter}{50}
\setcounter{mycounter}{0}
\end{document}
```

---

Alternatively just set the text once and use the standard `\label`/`\ref` mechanism to handle the forward reference via the `aux` file. Which requires two passes of LaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\begin{document}


My total is \ref{thistot} % now holds 150
Cool ability [50] \addtocounter{mycounter}{50}
Cool ability [50] \addtocounter{mycounter}{50}
Cool ability [50] \addtocounter{mycounter}{50}
\addtocounter{mycounter}{-1}\refstepcounter{mycounter}\label{thistot}
\setcounter{mycounter}{0}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, my answer at [LaTeX3: Elegant way to forward-reference a counter with a "future" value](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587462/latex3-elegant-way-to-forward-reference-a-counter-with-a-future-value/588071#588071) might provide a way forward, alleviating the need to enter the data twice.

It uses a token cycle to evaluate the tokens of the `pointtracker` environment, in search of point allocations corresponding to `\addtopoints` invocations.  It then prints out the environment contents, placing the sum total of points allocated at the head of the environment.

While not shown here (see referenced answer), the environment may be nested.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tokcycle}[2021-05-27]
\usepackage{environ}
\newcounter{pointcount}
\newcommand\addtopoints[1]{(\textit{#1 point}%
  \ifnum#1=1\relax\else\textit{s}\fi)}
\def\z{\tcpop\Q\addtocounter{pointcount}{\Q}\tcpushgroup{\Q}}
\NewEnviron{pointtracker}[2][points]{%
  \par\bigskip\resettokcycle
  \setcounter{pointcount}{0}%
  \Macrodirective{\addcytoks{##1}\tctestifx{\addtopoints##1}{\z}{}}%
  \def\tmp{\tokencyclexpress{\Large\bfseries #2: \thepointcount{} #1}}%
  \expandafter\tmp\BODY\endtokencyclexpress
}
\begin{document}
\begin{pointtracker}[total points]{
Sum of Cool Abilities} % now holds 150

Cool ability A \addtopoints{50}

Cool ability B \addtopoints{50}

Cool ability C \addtopoints{50}
\end{pointtracker}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Above, I show a phrased (words and numbers) expression for the individual point values.  To match something more simple, in line with the OP's code, one would merely simplify the definition of `\addtopoints`, for example, to

```
\newcommand\addtopoints[1]{[\textit{#1}]}
```

Comment: Very interesting, and I'd upvote it if I could. It's probably what I'll go with in the (near) future once I understand it better.

Comment: @WormofLove See https://ctan.org/pkg/tokcycle for documentation and example files regarding tokcycle.  It  is a package to help users write tools that involve examining the individual tokens of the input stream.

Comment: @WormofLove, the logic here is that the tokens of the environment are collected for later typesetting.  However, if the macro `\addtopoints` is encountered along the way, it executes `\z`, which pops the next input (the point value), adds it to the cumulative count, and then pushes the point value back on the input stream, to allow the token collection to continue.  At the conclusion of the collection, the environment output of collected tokens includes the total point tally at the outset.

Answer (score 0):

E.g., looking at

```
My total is \themycounter 
Cool ability [50] \addtocounter{mycounter}{50}
Cool ability [50] \addtocounter{mycounter}{50}
Cool ability [50] \addtocounter{mycounter}{50}
```

the following questions arise:

- What do you want to see in the resulting .pdf-file coming from `\themycounter`?  (Obviously -- represented in decimal notation, using Arabic digits -- the value which the counter `mycounter` has at some moment in time. Which moment in time?)
- What is the correlation betwween `50` in `[50]` and `50` in `\addtocounter{mycounter}{50}`?

If you think you can lightheartedly have TeX carry out the same token sequence twice, but once with suppressing outputting things to the output file/.pdf file, you may be overlooking some funny problems.

Let's imagine this token sequence does other things besides outputting to the .pdf file. All these other things are then done twice. You don't necessarily want that. E.g., you don't want to have a counter globally incremented twice. You don't want to have things like `\immediate\write` to be carried out twice. You don't want a random-number-generator to be carried out twice, the second time delivering a value differing from the value delivered the first time. But such things can happen even if you work with a box-register whose content is not typeset.

So you would need a mechanism where you can specify

- which things to be done in the first pass (calculation of values of "variables").
- which things to be done in the second pass (delivering stuff to be typeset to the output-file/.pdf-file).
- whether the current pass is to be considered the first pass=the calculation-pass.
- whether the current pass is to be considered the second pass=the delivering to output-file/.pdf-file-pass.

So you would end up with a mechanism where de facto calculation is separated from outputting -- of course you could easily do something like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{mycounter}
\newif\ifcalculate
\newif\ifdelivertooutputfile

\newcommand\DoCalculationsOnly{\calculatetrue\delivertooutputfilefalse}
\newcommand\DoDeliverToOutputfileOnly{\calculatefalse\delivertooutputfiletrue}

\begin{document}

\DoCalculationsOnly
\ifdelivertooutputfile\noindent My total is \themycounter\\\fi
\ifdelivertooutputfile Cool ability [50]\\\fi
\ifcalculate\addtocounter{mycounter}{50}\fi
\ifdelivertooutputfile Cool ability [50]\\\fi
\ifcalculate\addtocounter{mycounter}{50}\fi
\ifdelivertooutputfile Cool ability [50]\fi
\ifcalculate\addtocounter{mycounter}{50}\fi

\DoDeliverToOutputfileOnly
\ifdelivertooutputfile\noindent My total is \themycounter\\\fi
\ifdelivertooutputfile Cool ability [50]\\\fi
\ifcalculate\addtocounter{mycounter}{50}\fi
\ifdelivertooutputfile Cool ability [50]\\\fi
\ifcalculate\addtocounter{mycounter}{50}\fi
\ifdelivertooutputfile Cool ability [50]\fi
\ifcalculate\addtocounter{mycounter}{50}\fi

% \setcounter{mycounter}{0}
% In case the package hyperref is in use resetting counters leads to
% uniqueness of names of automatically created named destinations not
% being ensured any more, thus I suggest not doing this but doing
% something similar to what is done in my subsequent examples.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I guess that -- as Ulrike Fischer said -- you could probably easily use the cross-referencing-mechanism:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand\mycountermacro{0}
\newcommand\resetmycounter{\gdef\mycountermacro{0}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\themycounter{\@arabic{\mycountermacro}}
\makeatother

\newcommand\AddAbility[2]{%
  \\%
  \xdef\mycountermacro{\number\numexpr\mycountermacro+#2\relax}%
  \refstepcounter{mycounter}%
  #1 [#2]%
}

\begin{document}

\resetmycounter
\noindent Total of character A is \ref*{TotalOfCharacterA}
\AddAbility{Cool ability of character A}{50}
\AddAbility{Another cool of character A}{40}
\AddAbility{Yet another cool ability of character A}{30}
\label{TotalOfCharacterA}

\noindent\hrulefill

\resetmycounter
\noindent Total of character B is \ref*{TotalOfCharacterB}
\AddAbility{Cool ability of character B}{5}
\AddAbility{Another cool of character B}{4}
\AddAbility{Yet another cool ability of character B}{3}
\label{TotalOfCharacterB}

\noindent\hrulefill

\resetmycounter
\noindent Total of character C is \ref*{TotalOfCharacterC}
\AddAbility{Cool ability of character C}{25}
\AddAbility{Another cool of character C}{20}
\AddAbility{Yet another cool ability of character C}{15}
\label{TotalOfCharacterC}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

If you don't want to calculate in integers only, you can implement a similar approach, using some math-library, e.g., pgfmath:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfmath}

\newcounter{mycounter}
\newcommand\mycountermacro{0}
\newcommand\resetmycounter{\gdef\mycountermacro{0}}
\renewcommand\themycounter{\mycountermacro}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\AddAbility[2]{%
  \\%
  \begingroup
  \pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,fixed,precision=2,fixed zerofill=true}%
  \pgfmathparse{\mycountermacro+#2}%
  \pgfmathroundtozerofill{\pgfmathresult}%
  \global\let\mycountermacro=\pgfmathresult
  \refstepcounter{mycounter}%
  #1 [\pgfmathparse{#2}\pgfmathroundtozerofill{\pgfmathresult}\pgfmathresult]%
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\def\expandafter\@currentlabel\expandafter{\@currentlabel}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\resetmycounter
\noindent Total of character A is \ref*{TotalOfCharacterA}
\AddAbility{Cool ability of character A}{50.1}
\AddAbility{Another cool of character A}{40.69}
\AddAbility{Yet another cool ability of character A}{30.2}
\label{TotalOfCharacterA}

\noindent\hrulefill

\resetmycounter
\noindent Total of character B is \ref*{TotalOfCharacterB}
\AddAbility{Cool ability of character B}{5.15}
\AddAbility{Another cool of character B}{4.62}
\AddAbility{Yet another cool ability of character B}{3.22}
\label{TotalOfCharacterB}

\noindent\hrulefill

\resetmycounter
\noindent Total of character C is \ref*{TotalOfCharacterC}
\AddAbility{Cool ability of character C}{25.02}
\AddAbility{Another cool of character C}{20.06}
\AddAbility{Yet another cool ability of character C}{15.01}
\label{TotalOfCharacterC}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

---

If a statblock is a component of a database, the package [datatool](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool) might be of interest.